# iOS 5 accelerometer data using javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, web, accelerometer

We used to be able to call accelerationIncludingGravity in javascript to access accelerometer data in iOS 4.2+, however, it is not working in iOS 5.1.1 on my iPad anymore. Is this normal? Are there any workaround?

Code that used to work:

```
    window.addEventListener('devicemotion', function (e) {
        x1 = e.accelerationIncludingGravity.x;
        y1 = e.accelerationIncludingGravity.y;
        z1 = e.accelerationIncludingGravity.z;          
    }
    , false);
```